# App crashes when running app on iphone vs simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

When I run my app in the 6.1 simulator, everything works fine. When I test run it on my iPhone 5 IOS 6.1.3, everything in the app works like a charm, except the following piece of code:

```
someText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
```

This line of code appears in a section where I calculate statistics using data in a database.

Could anyone point me in some direction because I cannot understand why just this line of code does not work. I have the same line of code in another part of this section and that breaks too. Numerical (int, double) does not have the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens? Is there an error? Add the complete error to your question.

Comment: Please paste the crash log....

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app and reinstalling! May be it has a old database schema.